# Netty SslHandler handshake timeout after removal

Tags: java, netty

Part of our application requires removing/adding SSL handlers in our Netty pipeline, we set a timeout on the SSL handshake to try and prevent [Slowloris attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)). We're using Netty 4.1.44.Final.

When creating an SslHandler based on a server SSLEngine, we set a 2 second handshake timeout. However if the channel is idle for 1 second, we will replace the SslHandler with a new one with a client SSLEngine that will be able to successfully handshake. However the pipeline receives an `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out` from the original SslHandler.

Is there a better way to do this dynamic replacement of SslHandlers that allows setting a handshake timeout?

Comment: I raised a Netty issue regarding this issue - https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/10158

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the netty bug tracker this is a bug